# blender threejs exports file without bones and in wrong format

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I've been trying to follow a tutorial at unboring.net on how to export animated meshes from blender to threejs. Everything works fine when i use the eva-animated.blend file provided by the writer of the tutorial. However, when i attempted to create my own mesh and export it to threejs, the result is in the wrong format and the bone data seems to not be included.

My file: monkey.blend. Url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4iDXLNwo9_WmtmSXBEWVhBa2s/view Output format:

```
{
  data: {
    attributes: {
      position: {
        type: "Float32Array",
        array: [...],
        itemSize: 3
      },
      normal: {
        type: "Float32Array",
        array: [...],
        itemSize: 3
      },
      uv: {
        type: "Float32Array",
        array: [...],
        itemSize: 2
      }
    },
    index: {
      type: "Uint16Array",
      array: [...],
      itemSize: 1
    }
  },
  metadata: {
    position: 2898,
    version: 3,
    uv: 2898,
    type: "BufferGeometry",
    normal: 2898,
    generator: "io_three"
  }
}
```

The writer's file: eva-animated.blend. Url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4iDXLNwo9_eXZTWlBkdlp3SzA/view Output:

```
{
  normals: [...],
  metadata: {
    normals: 762,
    generator: "io_three",
    vertices: 738,
    version: 3,
    uvs: 1,
    materials: 1,
    bones: 33,
    type: "Geometry",
    faces: 762
  },
  skinWeights: [...],
  vertices: [...],
  bones: [..],
  animations: [...],
  uvs: [...],
  skinIndices: [...],
  materials: [...],
  name: "BodyGeometry.6",
  influencesPerVertex: 2,
  faces: [...]
}
```

The data for monkey is just not loading in threejs, while eva-animated works perfectly. I want to know what is wrong with my monkey.blend file, because I've tried everything and I just can't get the output to be correct. My file has a rigged mesh, one simple animation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your file and I got the bones
Are you exporting using the `BufferGeometry` type or the `Geometry` ?

I'm using the `Geometry` type and I'm getting the bones
However I didn't test the animation, I only opened the file